# Is there any stable method on the SparkSession/SparkContext/RDD that we can call to easily detect when eviction is happening?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is there any stable method on the SparkSession/SparkContext/RDD that we can call to easily detect when eviction is happening?

For more context see [Disable new Spark behaviour of evicting cached partitions when insufficient memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69506587/disable-new-spark-behaviour-of-evicting-cached-partitions-when-insufficient-memo) or [When was automatic Spark RDD partition cache eviction implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69597745/when-was-automatic-spark-rdd-partition-cache-eviction-implemented/69597920#69597920)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve `RddInfo` array from SparkContext, and interrogate its elements for the partition counts of an RDD you're interested in. If some of the partitions were evicted/didnt fit into executor storage, the number `numCachedPartitions` will be less than total number of RDD's partitions `numPartitions`.

```
scala> val rdd = sc.textFile("file:///etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf").repartition(10)
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[9] at repartition at <console>:27

scala> rdd.persist().count()
res14: Long = 34

scala> val rddStorage = rdd.context.getRDDStorageInfo(0)
rddStorage: org.apache.spark.storage.RDDInfo = RDD "MapPartitionsRDD" (9) StorageLevel: StorageLevel(memory, deserialized, 1 replicas); CachedPartitions: 10; TotalPartitions: 10; MemorySize: 5.1 KB; DiskSize: 0.0 B

scala> val fullyCached = (rddStorage.numCachedPartitions == rddStorage.numPartitions)
fullyCached: Boolean = true
```

Zero in the above, `...getRDDStorageInfo(0)`, is used for illustration purposes only. In reality, instead of simply using `0`, you'd need to get the `id` of an RDD you're interested in (see [`RDD.id`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#id:Int)), and then iterate through the `RDDInfo[]` array to find the element with `rddInfo.id = id`.  You can probably also use `rddInfo.name` to do the same thing if you give the RDD a name.

Finally, you could just detect if *any* RDD has eviction with something like this:

```
sparkSession
  .sparkContext.getRDDStorageInfo.filter(_.isCached)
  .find(rdd => rdd.numCachedPartitions < rdd.numPartitions)
  .foreach(rdd =>
          throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"RDD is being evicted, please configure cluster with more memory. " +
            s"numCachedPartitions = ${rdd.numCachedPartitions}, " +
            s"numPartitions = ${rdd.numPartitions}, " +
            s"name = ${rdd.name}, " +
            s"id = ${rdd.id}, " +
            s"memSize = ${rdd.memSize}, " +
            s"diskSize = ${rdd.diskSize}, " +
            s"externalBlockStoreSize = ${rdd.externalBlockStoreSize}"
          ))
```

Comment: Good edits, thanks @samthebest!