Get the list of actually persisted DataFrames in Spark
I am using Databricks notebooks. I want to programmatically find the list of DataFrames that have actually been cached by an action call, that is where .cache() was followed by an action, like .show().
This post gives a solution for the simpler case: finding the objects where either .cache() or .persist() have been called and hence the is_cached attribute is set to True, but there is no guarantee that caching was triggered.
I tried sc._jsc.getPersistentRDDs() but it also returns java objects that I don't want to see; they have nothing to do with my actual code, and it is hard to figure out which item (if any) is my cached dataframe, see toy example below.
How could I proceed?


Could you please provide what you are getting and your sample output?

I added a new, fifth cell to show the output, if that's what you meant. This is also a good point to note that the return value from sc._jsc.getPersistentRDDs() changes from time to time, now it is 80+, even if I don't do anything with my notebook, so it is hard to find/spot my cached df in this fluctuating sea of java objects...

I'm not clear what you expect such a "list of dataframes" to look like, but maybe this can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69596441/is-there-any-stable-method-on-the-sparksession-sparkcontext-rdd-that-we-can-call/69598148#69598148 Spoiler: It ain't gonna be the list of your python variable names for sure :))

The solution I linked above gives a superset of what I wanted. No big deal, I can loop through all objects and call .unpersist() even if they have not actually been persisted; in that case .unpersist() is a no-op I guess.

I have tried the below approach:
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark import StorageLevel
cached_dfs = []
def cache_and_track(df: DataFrame, name: str):
    """
    Caches a DataFrame and tracks its name.
    This function ensures the DataFrame is cached and marked as "used".
    """
    df.cache()  
    cached_dfs.append((name, df))
    return df
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([('a', 1), ('b', 2)], ["letter", "number"])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([('x', 3), ('y', 4)], ["char", "num"])
df1 = cache_and_track(df1, "df1")
# df2 = cache_and_track(df2, "df2") 
df1.show()
# df2.count() 
actual_cached_dfs = [name for name, df in cached_dfs if df.storageLevel != StorageLevel.NONE]
print("DataFrames that were actually cached and triggered:")
print(actual_cached_dfs)

Results:
+------+------+
|letter|number|
+------+------+
|     a|     1|
|     b|     2|
+------+------+

DataFrames that were actually cached and triggered:
['df1']


In the above code creating a list to store references to cached DataFrames
Marking DataFrame for caching
Cache DataFrames and track them by name
Triggering actions & Checking which DataFrames have been cached and accessed

thanks, but try comment out df2.count() and see what you get. The same as above, meaning you don't actually list what has really been persisted to memory (df1) but both. I would like to see 'df1' only

i have tried commenting out the df2 and updated the results can you check and let me know for any  questions please.

I think your logic (checking storageLevel) cannot give an answer to my question. You keep track of the dataframes on which .cache() has been called and not the ones (the subset) on which a further action has been called. I am only interested in the subset, because these are the ones, strictly speaking, that will have to be unpersisted to prevent memory leak. Now I think the solution is simple (based on your idea): track only the 'actioned' dataframes in a global list.

Yes, got it let me try that and update the solution for you.
